# I'm trying to store path in Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: c, path, dijkstra, shortest

I'm trying to store the path Dijkstra's does when it calculates shortest path to every vertice from the source. This is currently what I'm doing right now but I'm struggling with how to actually store the path. I was hoping if someone can help me. You should also note that currently the u value's are ints and I want to return this specific path as characters. The array size is 26 by 26 as there are 26 characters in the alphabet. A possible path could be C B A, or 2, 1, 0.

```
void dijkstra(int graph[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS], int src){
    int dist[MAX_ROWS];     // The output array.  dist[i] will hold the shortest distance from src to i
    bool sptSet[MAX_ROWS]; // sptSet[i] will true if vertex i is included in shortest path tree or shortest distance from src to i is finalized
    int i, count, v;
    struct path {
        char thepath[40];
    } pathArray[MAX_ROWS];
    // Initialize all distances as INFINITE and stpSet[] as false
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++)
        dist[i] = INT_MAX, sptSet[i] = false;
    // Distance of source vertex from itself is always 0
    dist[src] = 0;

    // Find shortest path for all vertices
    for (count = 0; count < MAX_ROWS-1; count++){
        // Pick the minimum distance vertex from the set of vertices not
        // yet processed. u is always equal to src in first iteration.
        int u = minDistance(dist, sptSet);
        int baby = u + 'A';
        char girl = baby;
        printf("Count : %d,  u : %c\n", count, girl);
        pathArray[v].thepath[v] = girl;
        // Mark the picked vertex as processed
        sptSet[u] = true;
        // Update dist value of the adjacent vertices of the picked vertex.
        for (v = 0; v < MAX_ROWS; v++)
            // Update dist[v] only if is not in sptSet, there is an edge from
            // u to v, and total weight of path from src to  v through u is
            // smaller than current value of dist[v]
            if (!sptSet[v] && graph[u][v] && dist[u] != INT_MAX  && dist[u]+graph[u][v] < dist[v]){
                dist[v] = dist[u] + graph[u][v];
            }
    }
    // print the constructed distance array
    printf("Vertex   Distance from Source\n");
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++){
        if (dist[i] != INT_MAX)
            printf("%d \t\t %d Path: %s\n", i, dist[i], pathArray[i].thepath);
    }
    //printSolution(dist, MAX_ROWS, pathArray.thepath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of `pathArray` has some problems:

- First, you address the path via the vertex `v`, but `v` is uninitialised and it does not have any meaning outside the `for` loop.
- Also, `v` isn't any meaningful information for the string: It is a vertex id. You also have the distance to the source, but the string index you need requires the number of steps to reach `v` from the source vertex, which you currently don't store.
- Finally, you can only build your paths when all distances have been found, not during pathfinding.

A better approach is to keep an array `prev[MAX_ROWS]` that stores the vertex id of the vertex that lies directly before this vertex in the shortest path from the source to this vertex. That means you essentially store the path from the destination to the source. You can't do it the other way round, because the paths from the source may fork. Seen from the other end, that means that all paths eventually join when going towards the source, so storing the path as list of previous points is safe.

You set the previous vertex whenever you find a new shortest distance:

```
if (!sptSet[v] && graph[u][v] && dist[u] != INT_MAX
&& dist[u]+graph[u][v] < dist[v])
{
    dist[v] = dist[u] + graph[u][v];
    prev[v] = u;
}
```

You can then print the path from each vertex `i` to the source:

```
v = i;
while (v != src) {
    putchar('A' + v);
    v = prev[v];
}
putchar('A' + src);
putchar(10);
```

If you want to store the forward-going path, you can implement a recursive approach or write the path to a string and then reverse it.

Comment: This does not store the path for every individual vertice from the source, and the loop you have provided simply returns a bus error. What I'm trying to accomplish is to store the shortest paths from the source to all it's destinations in an array.

Comment: @Zeusftw: This code does store the shortest path from every vertex to the source. (Well, it doesn't store it, just prints it, but that's what you do in your original code too.) The bus error is very likely because you write to `pathArray` at uninitialised indices. Please delete that portion of the code; it gave me weird errors when I tested the code.